# Prove that over an infinite field, a finite set of points in $\mathbb{ A}^n$ can be obtained as vanishing set of n polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

While reading Ernst Kunz's *commutative algebra* book, I came across this problem:

> Let $K$  be an infinite field, and $V \in\mathbb{ A}^n (K)$ (the affine n-space) be a finite set of points. Show that the *ideal* of $V$, i.e. {$f(x_1,\dots,x_n) : f(p) = 0 \forall p\in V$} is generated by *exactly* n polynomials.

For $|V| = 1$ this is obvious, since the ideal $(x_1 - a_1, ..., x_n - a_n)$ works. The book says to use interpolation as a hint, but I have no clue how to use it (to be honest, being a pure math student I haven't handled interpolation in my life). Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't give the sharp bound, though.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: What I meant to say was that the number of polynomials is the same as the dimension of the affine n-space. I have edited my question a little to make it clearer.